# React.js: Use Header-Imported Javascript Library

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, amplitude-analytics

I have built a React.js web app and am trying to use Amplitude Analytics, which has a Javascript SDK [here](https://github.com/amplitude/Amplitude-Javascript):

The instructions say to include a `<script></script>` in the `<head></head>` part of the page. I've added the script in my `index.html` page, and was wondering how I can use the library in my `.jsx` files.

This is an event tracking library, and to record an event, I need to call `amplitude.getInstance().logEvent('EVENT_IDENTIFIER_HERE');`. However, I'm not sure how to import `amplitude` so that it becomes available in my `Main.jsx` or my `Page1Component.jsx` file?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried calling `amplitude.getInstance().logEvent("YOUR_API_KEY_HERE");` in your JSX files?

Comment: @IgorNikolaev yes and it does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been suggested to:
`npm install amplitude/Amplitude-Javascript --save`
which would install the library from github instead from the npm registry.

Then you can import it in your code:

```
import amplitude from 'amplitude-js/amplitude.min'
```

Reference: https://github.com/amplitude/Amplitude-Javascript/issues/40